# Ways to zoom in WPF

Tags: wpf, zooming

I Need to implement zoom same as in office 2010.

The content can be any UI element including a third party grid(probably telerik)

I know 4 ways to implement zoom.

What the best way(performance) to implement zoom in this case?

Comment: whats your 4 ways? i do zoom with scaletransform.

Comment: ViewBox, Layout Transform(scale), DocumentViewer, Canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout transform is the most flexible and efficient way to zoom and keep the layout as designed in first place.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the simplest, fastest way to zoom is to set the `RenderTransform` on the element to be zoomed as a `ScaleTransform`, and set the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of the transform.

Comment: RenderTransform Not good for complex windows, need to use LayoutTransform

Comment: RenderTransform is certainly the most performant way. Why do you need LayoutTransform?

Comment: Render transform will cause your items to overlay each other inside a panel for example.. it does not consider this overlaying issue so its useless for complex screens...

Comment: Also if you want scrolling when zooming it will never work with renderTransform.

Comment: Why the downvote? RenderTransform is definitely the way to go, if you really want zooming with panning. Layouttransform is always centered. Also @ChenKinnrot Nothing is overlapping if you apply the render transform to the panel, not each individual item. For simple stuff LayoutTransform might be suffice, but if i need more control there is no way around RenderTransform.

Comment: I agree with Chen: RenderTransform only scales the content of some element, but does not resize the element itself. So the content will be drawn over the border. In contrast, LayoutTransform will resize the element itself to make the scaled content fit to it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Viewbox Component Such as Below

```
<Viewbox Width="..." Height="...">
    <Grid>     
       .
       .
       .
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use canvas to draw yuor controls in it it supports zoom resize and rotation

Comment: Please elaborate... eg explain what "canvas" is and where one could find it?